Customizable DynamoDB attributes in CloudFormation
I am working on DynamoDB table CloudFormation template. I am interested if it's possible to create parameter with type CommaDelimitedList and specify there several attributes that will be used dynamically in AttributeDefinitions sections of AWS::DynamoDB::Table resource. Something like:
Parameters:

  TableAdditionalAttributes:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: Comma-separated list of additional attributes
    Default: "Test,N,Also,S,Maybe,S"

Resources: 

  DynamoDBTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties: 
      TableName: TableName
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: PartitionKey
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: SortKey
          AttributeType: S
        # Loop through additional attributes
        - !If
          - HasAdditionalAttributes
          - !Split
            - ","
            - !Join [",", !Ref TableAdditionalAttributes]
          - []

Unfortunately, I don't have success with code above. Any suggestions please?
I tried several ways of splitting list to succeed but I still encountering issues.

Can you explain why you're trying to do this? You only need to specify Key-Attributes in advance, i.e. Partition and Sort Key + those for Secondary Indexes.

It's because I try to create reusable template where users can use it and create tables as they need with custom columns (they have limited access to AWS and editing code). They only can define mentioned parameters.

You don't define non-key attributes when creating DynamoDB tables. You only need to define keys, which you have already hard coded in the template, so the need to loop through additional attributes is neither needed, or works.
